# How To Write A Formula For The First N Terms of a Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

So I have the sequence $$\{5, 15, 45,\cdots\}$$ and I figured out that the formula to find a particular term is $$S_n = 5 \times 3^{n-1}$$ but how do I use this to find the sum of the first $n$ terms?

Comment: You can factor $5$ out of the sum and you are left with a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that, for $n=1,2,\cdots$,
$$
1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}, \qquad x \neq 1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

> **Geometric Summation:** Given the sequence$$a,ar,ar^2,ar^3,\ldots,ar^{n-1}\tag1$$
>   We have the sum as$$S=a\left(\frac {1-r^n}{1-r}\right)\tag2$$
>   Where $S$ is the total sum and $a$ is the first term of the sequence.

**Proof:** Multiplying $S$ by $r$, we obtain another equation$$Sr=ar+ar^2+ar^3+\ldots+ar^n\tag3$$
And subtracting $Sr$ from $S$, we have$$S-Sr=a-ar^n=a\left(1-r^n\right)\implies \boxed{S=a\frac {1-r^n}{1-r}}\tag4$$

For example, if you wanted to find the sum of the first two terms $5+15$, we see that $a=5$, $r=3$ and $n=2$. Thus, the sum is$$S=5\cdot\frac {1-3^2}{1-3}=20$$
Trying out the first $5$ sums, we have $5+15+45+135+405$. Therefore,$$S=5\cdot\frac {1-3^5}{1-3}=605$$
And verifying, we see that indeed, the sum is $605$.$$5+15+45+135+405=605$$